# error C2872: 'range_error' : ambiguous symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pointers, ambiguous

I have already searched SO and google, I am not declaring the same variable in two places nor am I including something in a weird way..that I know of. The insert method should be working fine, it's a pre-written method(i guess that could be wrong too.. lol). This is the error I get.

**Error:**

```
error C2872: 'range_error' : ambiguous symbol
........ while compiling class template member function 'Error_code List<List_entry>::insert(int,const List_entry &)'
```

To me the insert method looks alright, I don't see any problems with the position variable which is being compared to 0 or count which is declared as 0 in the constructor to return the range_error.

**Insert Method:**

```
template <class List_entry>
Error_code List<List_entry>::insert(int position, const List_entry &x){
    Node<List_entry> *new_node, *following, *preceding;
    if(position < 0 || position > count){
        return range_error;
    }
    if(position == 0){
        if(count == 0) following = nullptr;
        else {
            set_position(0);
            following = current;
        }
        preceding = nullptr;
    }
    else {
        set_position(position - 1);
        preceding = current;
        following = preceding->next;
    }

    new_node = new Node<List_entry>(x, preceding, following);

    if(new_node == nullptr) return overflow;
    if(preceding != nullptr) preceding->next = new_node;
    if(following != nullptr) following->back = new_node;

    current = new_node;
    current_position = position;
    count++;

    return success;
}
```

Could the problem be in that I don't have an implementation of the overloaded = operator?

**All code here: [pastie.org/1258159](http://pastie.org/1258159)**

Comment: `return range_error;`  What is `range_error`?

Comment: Where is range_error defined? (Work firewall blocks the site with the code)

Comment: range_error is defined by enum Error_code{success, underflow, overflow, range_error}; in the node.h

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`range_error` is defined both in your code (in the global namespace) and by the Standard Library (in the `std` namespace). Your use of `using namespace std;` to drag the entire Standard namespace into the global namespace creates an ambiguity. You should do at least one of the following:

- remove `using namespace std` from the global namespace; either use the namespace within your functions, or use just the names you need, or qualify all the standard names when you use them
- carefully choose your own names to avoid conflicts with standard names
- place your own names inside a namespace (and don't pull that into the global namespace).

Comment: Thank you for the amazing answer! I actually learned something!

Answer (score 2):

`range_error` is a class defined in the `stdexcept` header. In your code you probably use a constant with the same name and make `std::range_error` visible with an `using namespace std;` directive which results in the ambiguity. Either rename your constant or revise your using directives.

For example:

```
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

int range_error = 42;

int main()
{
    return range_error;
}
```

The code above causes the same error.

Comment: there is only one range_error declaration and implementation. See here http://pastie.org/1258159

Comment: Right, but there is another in the standard header, so I would recommend you replacing `using namespace std;` with only using declaration that you need, e.g. `using std::cout;`, etc. Alternatively rename your `range_error` to something else, e.g. `out_of_range`.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `using namespace std;` statement at the top brings in declaration of [`std::range_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/range_error) exception from `stdexcept` header. This conflicts with your `enum` value. Enclose the `enum` in a `struct` and fully qualify:

```
struct my_errors {
    enum {
        // ...
        range_error
    };
};
// ...
return my_errors::range_error;
```

Or just avoid using names from the standard library.

Comment: If I could vote your answer, I would. Thanks for the suggestion. In this situation I can't change the name of Error_code. But when I can i'll be sure to keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution (in addition to those already given) is to qualify the name, `::range_error`. That's what namespaces are for. It's why the standard lib stuff is down in namespace `std`, so that such conflicts can be *very* easily resolved.

In the code presented above,

```
if(new_node == nullptr) return overflow;
```

will never execute the `return`.

Can you see why?

Cheers & hth.,

PS: Re the pastebook code, note that `main` must have result type `int`, not `void`. Also, many functions fail to return a value.